# Why does Nokogiri require only work in super-user mode?

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, nokogiri

I keep getting an error when I run a file called wc.rb. I type:

```
ruby wc.rb
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from wc.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

However, it works when I run the same script with:

```
    sudo ruby wc.rb
```

Is there anything I can do so that I don't have to run this script as a super user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run with `sudo` are you running the same version of Ruby? If `sudo ruby -v` returns something different than `ruby -v`, you may have only installed the Nokogiri gem in the Ruby 2.0 gem location, and not for the gem location associated with your system's default version of Ruby.

**Update:** If you originally installed the Nokogiri gem using `sudo`, you also may need to uninstall it first using sudo (`sudo gem uninstall nokogiri`) and re-install it without using `sudo` (`gem install nokogiri`) for the permissions to be correct.

Comment: same versons of ruby `sudo ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-linux]
+8:01% ruby -v     
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: What is listed under `GEM PATHS` when you run `gem env` and `sudo gem env`?

Comment: same output for both again.

Comment: Did you install nokogiri gem using `sudo`? If so, can you try `sudo gem uninstall nokogiri` and then reinstall it without sudo?